# Core Data & Xcode 11: Please switch to using "NSSecureUnarchiveFromData" or a subclass of NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, core-data-migration

Just moved to Xcode 11 and getting the following crash at launch:

> CoreData: fault: One or more models in this application are using transformable properties with transformer names that are either unset, or set to NSKeyedUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName. Please switch to using "NSSecureUnarchiveFromData" or a subclass of NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer instead. At some point, Core Data will default to using "NSSecureUnarchiveFromData" when nil is specified, and transformable properties containing classes that do not support NSSecureCoding will become unreadable.
>
> CoreData: warning: Property 'color' on Entity 'Group' is using nil or an insecure NSValueTransformer.  Please switch to using "NSSecureUnarchiveFromData" or a subclass of NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer instead.

I'm creating an `NSPersistentContainer` at launch using the code below:

```
private let container: NSPersistentContainer = {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MyApp", managedObjectModel: MyAppModelVersion.current.managedObjectModel())
    let storeDescription = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: getStoreURLWithUserName())
    storeDescription.shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically = true
    storeDescription.shouldInferMappingModelAutomatically = true
    container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [storeDescription]
    return container
}()
```

Error occurs right after this line is executed:

```
let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MyApp", managedObjectModel: MyAppModelVersion.current.managedObjectModel())
```

I also have a property called 'Color`in a`Group` entity that's transformable:

```
@NSManaged public var color: UIColor?
@NSManaged public var hexColorValue: String?
```

Below is how set the property:

```
public var hexColor: String? {
    get {
        return self.hexColorValue
    }
    set {
        self.hexColorValue = newValue
        if let str = newValue {
            self.color = UIColor(hex: str)
        }
    }
}
```

This is what the property looks like in Core Data:

[image]

I am not sure how to recover from this crash.  This was working fine with Xcode 10

Comment: Please read the error carefully, it’s very clear. But why do you save both the color and the hex string representation? The latter is sufficient.

Comment: I would like to continue to use `nil` as it has been working fine.  I need to save hex and UIColor property with each record so that I don't have to convert back-and-forth.

Comment: You do **not** need to save both. The computed property provides the conversion and saving both is much more expensive. Otherwise do what the error suggests.

Comment: Thanks.  Any suggestions on how to get passed that error?

Comment: I was hoping to get some help with creating a `Transformer`.  I guess I'll have to figure it out and post a solution here.

Comment: Hello, have you solved the problem?

Comment: Not really.  I went around it and used `hexColor: String?` instead of storing `UIColor`

Answer (score 39):

****Swift 5.4.2****

This worked for me.

**EDIT** Link to the article is [here](https://www.kairadiagne.com/2020/01/13/nssecurecoding-and-transformable-properties-in-core-data.html).

- Click on the .xcdatamodeld file in the project navigator
- Click on the
  Entity that has a Transformable Attribute
- Click on the Transformable Attribute
- Click the 'Show Data Model Inspector' icon
- Enter 'NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer'
  in the Transformer field - **EDIT** Make this 'NSSecureUnarchiveFromData' *as of Swift 5.5.2.*

[image: editor_orientation_preview]

Your warnings/errors should go away.  If not, try cleaning your build folder and rebuild.

Comment: `Click the 'Show Data Model Inspector' icon` I cant find this icon..
UPDATE: I found it, I had to restart Xcode, then in the right sidebar, the tab with [this icon](https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/2680616/filter_ios_mixer_options_settings_slider_web_icon) is the one. If it says `no selection`, restart Xcode, that solved it in my case.

Answer (score 28):

Setting Transformer property to NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer solved the warning in my case. For this select the attribute & set its transformer type to NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer & run again by pressing commond+R.

Thanks,
Ratneshwar

Comment: This won‘t work for `UIColor` as it‘s not supported by `NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer`.

Comment: What's about iOS 11? NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer' is only available in iOS 12.0 or newer

Answer (score 13):

This is related to a migration from `NSCoding` to the `NSSecureCoding` protocol. The default `ValueTransformer` adopts `NSCoding`, so the only solution that worked for me was to write my own `Transformer` that adopts the `NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer` protocol.

I should say that my own experience is from trying to define an Attribute with the Transformer type to persist a custom class that adopted `NSCoding`. I was initially met with a *warning* similar to the OP's *error*. I was able to suppress the warning by changing the Transformer field on the attribute to "NSSecureUnarchiveFromData" as others have mentioned, but I then received an error along the lines of:

`Not able to save to CoreData. SQLCore dispatchRequest Object of class “ ” not among allowed top level class list...` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58067115/not-able-to-save-to-coredata-sqlcore-dispatchrequest-object-of-class-not-am). The suggestion to change the Attribute to a Relationship was undesirable in my case.

More digging came up with [this blog post](https://www.kairadiagne.com/2020/01/13/nssecurecoding-and-transformable-properties-in-core-data.html) that details the "reason" for all of this, and gives a solution that worked for me. The blog actually uses the case of `UIColor` in the example, but it works for any custom class as well.

Say you have a `CustomClass` that you want to store as a Transformable Attribute in some Entity. If you're like me, you may have adopted `NSCoding` and received the aforementioned error. The solution would be to adopt `NSSecureCoding` instead and define an `NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer` subclass:

```
@objc(CustomClassValueTransformer)
final class CustomClassValueTransformer: NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer {

    static let name = NSValueTransformerName(rawValue: String(describing: CustomClass.self))

    // Make sure `CustomClass` is in the allowed class list,
    // AND any other classes that are encoded in `CustomClass`
    override static var allowedTopLevelClasses: [AnyClass] {
        // for example... yours may look different
        return [CustomClass.self, OtherClass.self, NSArray.self, NSValue.self]
    }

    /// Registers the transformer.
    public static func register() {
        let transformer = CustomClassValueTransformer()
        ValueTransformer.setValueTransformer(transformer, forName: name)
    }
}
```

Then make sure to set the Transformer field on your Attribute to "CustomClassValueTransformer" and the Custom Class field to "CustomClass" and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 3):

For the transformable attribute, you need to set its type in the Custom Class field.

For instance, I have a transformable field which stores an array of numbers and its Custom Class is declared as `[Int16]`. This is most likely the cause of the crash. And as @vadian mentioned before, you don't need both fields.

After your crash is fixed, you can get rid of the warning by setting the Transformer field to `NSSecureUnarchiveFromData` (you simply type this into the field)

Comment: I can't get this solution to work ! adding NSSecureUnarchiveFromData to the transformer field cause the project to crash. As for changing the custom classes field. This also causes a crash

Comment: The new name is actually 'NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer', so you're just missing the word 'Transformer' at the end :)

Answer (score 3):

For Objective-C and iOS 14, the following solution works for `UIColor` attributes.

- First add a new subclass of `NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer`

  `@interface ColorValueTransformer : NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer`
- Add the following static method to your implementation file:

  ```
  @implementation ColorValueTransformer

  + (NSArray<Class> *)allowedTopLevelClasses {
            return @[UIColor.class]; 
  }

  @end
  ```
- Open your data model (e.g. datamodel..xcdatamodeld)
- Select the entity and the related attribute which needs the new Transformer
- Open the Data Model Inspector
- Add the class name (e.g. `ColorValueTransformer`) as *Transformer* to that attribute
- Change the *Custom Class* to `UIColor`
- Build and run…

Comment: Can't get this to build. Setting Custom Class field to **UIColor** causes the auto generated file to set the variable to type UIColor but the file doesn't import UIKit so I get this error on the last line of below text.

`//  This file was automatically generated and should not be edited.  
import Foundation  
import CoreData. 

extension Themes {. 
    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Themes> {. 
        return NSFetchRequest<Themes>(entityName: "Themes"). 
    }. 

    @NSManaged public var backgroundColor: UIColor? //Cannot find type 'UIColor' in scope`

Comment: Fantastic. I've been updating a very old Core Data app that I didn't write and this was my last real hurdle. This worked perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I received the same warning messages when updating to Xcode 11, however in my case they are just warnings, but no crash.

In order to work out the best solution, I tried creating a stripped down sample app with just a single entity containing a transformable attribute. But it seems that no matter what I tried I could not reproduce the problem. The I copied the model file from my main app to the demo app, and of course that failed.

So I got to the point where I just had two model files and a simple unit test which does nothing more than open the model and create a persistent store container:

```
 func testDataModels() {
     openDataModel(named: "samplemodel")
     openDataModel(named: "appmodel")
 }

 func openDataModel(named name: String) {
    print("Opening \(name)")
     guard let url = findFile(forResource: name, withExtension: "momd"),
           let managedObjectModel = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: url)
     else {
         XCTFail("Unable to find \(name) data model")
         return
     }
    print(url)
     _ = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: managedObjectModel)
 }

 func findFile(forResource name: String, withExtension ext: String) -> URL? {
     if let url = Bundle(for: type(of: self)).url(forResource: name, withExtension: ext) {
         return url
     }
     return Bundle.main.url(forResource: name, withExtension: ext)
 }
```

The appmodel causes the error messsages but the sample model does not. Even when I stripped the appmodel down to a single Entity it continues to generate the errors.

Comparing the contents of the samplemodel with the appmodel (show package contents in Finder), there is a hidden file called .xccurrentversion in the samplemodel but not in the appmodel. The file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>_XCCurrentVersionName</key>
    <string>samplemodel.xcdatamodel</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

So I created a similar file for the appmodel and put it in the package folder. 
Surprisingly, that silences the warning messages! Conversely, deleting the .xccurrentversion file from the samplemodel causes the error messages to be generated. This will allow testing of the problem in isolation.

So this may be a short term fix. In the meantime, I need to work out how to migrate to secure coding.

Answer (score 0):

BEWARE !!!

I can confirm that both:

- NSSecureUnarchiveFromData
- NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer

Break iCloud Sync ⚠️⚠️. Do not use them.

Leave the Value Transformer Name Field empty (inspector) and keep the warning.