# Not able to save to CoreData. SQLCore dispatchRequest Object of class " " not among allowed top level class list

Tags: swift, core-data

I got this error message when I tried to save the data to core data. I think it got maybe something to do that some of the attributes in my Entities are of type Transformable.

Error Message:

```swift
[error] error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request: <NSSQLSaveChangesRequestContext: 0x60000029c8f0> , Object of class Address is not among allowed top level class list (
    NSArray,
    NSDictionary,
    NSSet,
    NSString,
    NSNumber,
    NSDate,
    NSData,
    NSURL,
    NSUUID,
    NSNull
) with userInfo of (null)
```

Entities and their attributes in the .xcdatamodeld file (screenshots):

1. [User Entity Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogGWD.png)
2. [Address Entity Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsiea.png)

---

User Class UPDATED:

```
@objc(User)
public class User: NSManagedObject, Decodable {

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case address, company , avatar, email, id, name, phone, username, website }

     required convenience public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

         guard let context = decoder.userInfo[.context] as? NSManagedObjectContext else { fatalError("NSManagedObjectContext is missing") }

         let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "User", in: context)!
         self.init(entity: entity, insertInto: context)

         let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

         address = try values.decode(Address.self, forKey: .address)
         avatar = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .avatar)
         company = try values.decode(Company.self, forKey: .company)
         email = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .email)
         id = try values.decode(Int32.self, forKey: .id)
         name = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
         phone = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .phone)
         username = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .username)
         website = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .website)

     }
}
```

---

Address Class UPDATED::

```
@objc(Address)
public class Address: NSManagedObject, Decodable {

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case geo, city, street, suite, zipcode }

        required convenience public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

            guard let context = decoder.userInfo[.context] as? NSManagedObjectContext else { fatalError("NSManagedObjectContext is missing") }

            let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Address", in: context)!
            self.init(entity: entity, insertInto: context)

            let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

                street = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .street)
                suite = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .suite)
                city = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .city)
                zipcode = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .zipcode)
                geo = try values.decode(Geo.self, forKey: .geo)
      }

}
```

---

Address Class UPDATED:

```
extension Address {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Address> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Address>(entityName: "Address")
    }

    @NSManaged public var city: String
    @NSManaged public var street: String
    @NSManaged public var suite: String
    @NSManaged public var zipcode: String
    @NSManaged public var geo: Geo

}
```

All suggestions and code samples are appreciated. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Core Data model is wrong.

Delete the attributes `address` and `company`. Both must be relationships.

- Select `User`, click on the + sign below relationship, name it `address`, select `Address` as destination.
- Select `Address`, click on the + sign below relationship, name it `user`, select `User` as destination and `address` as inverse.
- Go back to `User` and select `user` as inverse of the relationship.

Make sure that both relationships are to-one and that both @NSManaged objects are declared in the classes.

Do the same for `Company` and for the other wrong *Transformable* attributes.

And in `init(from decoder` you have to set one direction of the relationships explicitly.