# GoogleAnalytics.Property 'parameters' on Entity 'GAIHit' is using nil or an insecure NSValueTransformer

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics

After updating the GoogleAnalytics pod, my app started crashing with the following error:

> CoreData: fault: One or more models in this application are using
> transformable properties with transformer names that are either unset,
> or set to NSKeyedUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName. Please switch to
> using "NSSecureUnarchiveFromData" or a subclass of
> NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer instead. At some point, Core Data
> will default to using "NSSecureUnarchiveFromData" when nil is
> specified, and transformable properties containing classes that do not
> support NSSecureCoding will become unreadable. CoreData: warning:
> Property 'parameters' on Entity 'GAIHit' is using nil or an insecure
> NSValueTransformer.  Please switch to using
> "NSSecureUnarchiveFromData" or a subclass of
> NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer instead.

Can anybody help me fix it?

Comment: I'm getting this error in one of my app but it is not crashing.  Are you 100% confident the crash is indeed caused by Googe Analytics?

Comment: @CanabaltVi, anything new on this?

Comment: anything new? I am still getting this error.

Comment: Is there any update? am also getting the same error

Comment: This is not an error per se, this is really just Google not following Apple's deprecation. The real fix is stop using Google Analytics, and start using something more modern, like Firebase Analytics (and even that, it comes with a lot of strings attached)

All in all, if you can get away without 3rd-party analytics, and just use AppStore Connect Analytics, you will be far better off.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Core Data & Xcode 11: Please switch to using "NSSecureUnarchiveFromData" or a subclass of NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58053355/core-data-xcode-11-please-switch-to-using-nssecureunarchivefromdata-or-a-su)

Answer (score 0):

The fix is to set the transformer name to NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName on the transformable property in the data model.

1
2
@objc(GAIHit)
public class GAIHit: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged public var parameters: [String: Any]?

@objc(parameters)
@NSManaged public var parameters: [String: Any]?

{

transformerName = NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName

}

Comment: Hello, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help Thanks!