# fault: One or more models in this application are using transformable properties

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

After Updating my Pods, the app crashes with the below error:

> [error] fault: One or more models in this application are using
> transformable properties with transformer names that are either unset,
> or set to NSKeyedUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName. Please switch to
> using "NSSecureUnarchiveFromData" or a subclass of
> NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer instead. At some point, Core Data
> will default to using "NSSecureUnarchiveFromData" when nil is
> specified, and transformable properties containing classes that do not
> support NSSecureCoding will become unreadable.
>
> CoreData: fault: One or more models in this application are using
> transformable properties with transformer names that are either unset,
> or set to NSKeyedUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName. Please switch to
> using "NSSecureUnarchiveFromData" or a subclass of
> NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer instead. At some point, Core Data
> will default to using "NSSecureUnarchiveFromData" when nil is
> specified, and transformable properties containing classes that do not
> support NSSecureCoding will become unreadable.

Comment: Actually the error message is very descriptive. It even contains how to fix it.

Comment: @vadian how can it be solved? have not seen any place with NSKeyedUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Core Data & Xcode 11: Please switch to using "NSSecureUnarchiveFromData" or a subclass of NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58053355/core-data-xcode-11-please-switch-to-using-nssecureunarchivefromdata-or-a-su)